# Display <div> when hovering over another div and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML div and inside it has children.
I have a jQuery mouseover event attached to the div. Upon mouseover, I display another div and on mouseout, I hide it.

However when I mouseover the "premiumlink" div, all works well, but when I move my mouse over a child of the div, the div that is conditionally displayed hides, but then jQuery figures out that the parent div is still being hovered over, so it shows it again. Then if I move my cursor back to the parent div, the div is hidden then shown again.

How can I have the mouseover and mouseout apply to all children and not this jumpy state?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="platinumlevel" id="premiumlink">
    <h1>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/colorworld.png" alt="Logo" class="eventimage" />
        <a href="@Url.Action("Exhibitor1Attendee", "Home")" class="landing">Company Name</a>
    </h1>
    <div id="demopreview" style="display: none;">
        I should be displayed when "premiumlink" and all it's children are mouseovered
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#premiumlink").mouseover(function () {
    $('#demopreview').show(1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('#demopreview').hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: You want mouseenter, mouseleave. You do not even need JavaScript for this, plain old CSS can do it. `#premiumlink:hover #demopreview { display:  block } #demopreview { display: none; }`

Comment: Why not use [jQuery's `hover` event](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)? (which happens to bind to mouseenter and mouseleave).

Answer (score 1):

Change your event from mouseover to `mouseenter` en `mouseout` to `mouseleave`. These work way better and in pretty much all the major browsers.

[MDN Documentation on support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event#Browser_compatibility)

This is the code you'll need:

```
$("#premiumlink").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#demopreview').show(1000);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#demopreview').hide(1000);
});
```

If you don't want to use JavaScript and jQuery for this, the same can be done with CSS:

```
#demopreview {
    display: block
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

#premiumlink:hover #demopreview {
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Douwe de Haan* says, you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` respectively.

```
$('#premiumlink').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $('#demopreview').show(100);
});

$('#premiumlink').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#demopreview').hide(100);
});
```